# Can someone help me out with the table balancing done in MTT's?

Tags: tournament, mtt, balancing

Gone through the Pokerstars table balancing article:
https://www.pokerstars.com/help/articles/trn-table-balancing/10626/

**I am considering two major factors while developing my own online poker table balancing algorithm:**

- The number of times a player already moved from the table in a tournament, being a part of the table balancing algorithm.
- Player's relative position from the Big Blind position at the time of table break/balancing.

Now my concern is that whether I have to consider any more conditions (like an even distribution of *player's stack sizes* with respect to the other players' stacks at the table at the time of table break/merge, etc.) or the above-mentioned two factors will be enough?

Comment: Update : New players to a table as a result of balancing tables are dealt in immediately unless they are in the small blind or button position, where they must wait until the button has passed to the player on their left.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those 2 factors should be sufficient for the overwhelming majority of cases. If you're currently developing the code for doing that, you should probably stick to those 2 factors anyway, in order to reduce complexity. Over time, if you really want, you can add other rules to that algorithm.

PS: In my experience, in live MTTs, usually only the relative-position is taken into account, in order not to over-complicate the process and/or save time doing it.